# how to get return value from pytest fixture in a function so I don't need to call this function with additional parameter?

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

I have the following fixture in conftest.py that returns an environment settings dictionary like user, password etc:

```
@pytest.fixture
def envparams(request):
    env = request.config.getoption("--env")
    return env_params[env]
```

Then I have module like:

```
def request_master_url(envparams):
    cje_master_url = envparams['url']+'/'+test_master
    cje_user = envparams['user']
    cje_pass = envparams['password']
    local = testinfra.get_host("ssh://localhost")
    results = local.command(
                        'curl -L -I --user '+cje_user+':'
                        + cje_pass+' '+cje_master_url+'| grep HTTP\
                        |tail -1').stdout
    if '200 OK' in results:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

and a test that uses this module like:

```
def test_cje_high_availability(envparams, env_option, script_loc):
    workstation = testinfra.get_host('ssh://'+testinfra_hosts[0])
    if not security.request_master_url(envparams):
        print(test_master+' - is not available\n')
        create_team_master(test_master, envparams, script_loc)
```

Can I get rid of the envparams parameter from module function somehow so I can call it without additional parameter?
like:

```
security.request_master_url(envparams)
```

I only need to setup this fixture once in a session. I tried to use:

```
@pytest.mark.usefixtures('envparams')
def request_master_url():
```

But, I am not sure how to get values returned from this fixture.

Comment: Why not making a fixture out of `request_master_url`?

Comment: it's some solution, but I have many more functions like this one that are also using envparams fixture. I think it would be perhaps, better to create a global parameter in conftest.py and set it to envparams fixture for a session. I'll just read that from my module functions and no additional parameter would be needed to call from test functions.

Comment: Thing is, you can't apply `pytest` machinery to normal functions per se. If `request_master_url` should be a function and is used in tests only, you can get the env via `pytest.config.getoption('--env')` in the function directly, so you don't need to pass the `envparams` argument. Is this suitable to your needs?

Comment: yes, this was very helpfull actually. Implemented today.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've done as hoefling suggested.

Created small function in conftest.py:

```
def get_env_params():
    env_name = pytest.config.getoption("--env")
    return env_params[env_name]
```

and call it from my module functions where needed. Example function looks like below:

```
def request_master_url(team_id):
    envparams = get_env_params()
    cje_master_url = envparams['url']+'/'+team_id
    cje_user = envparams['user']
    cje_pass = envparams['password']
    local = testinfra.get_host("ssh://localhost")
    results = local.command(
                        'curl -L -I --user '+cje_user+':'
                        + cje_pass+' '+cje_master_url+'| grep HTTP\
                        |tail -1').stdout
    if '200 OK' in results:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

removed unnecessary fixture from many more functions and was able to clean my code a lot. Thanks!